# On the infimium of a functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis, geometric-analysis

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold. Define
$$\lambda(g)=\inf\{\mathcal{F}(g,f),\;0<f\in C^{\infty}(M),\; \int_Mf^2\;d\nu=1\},$$ 
where $$\mathcal{F}(g,f)=\int_M\left(|\nabla f|^2+ af^2\log f + bRf^2\right)\;d\nu,$$ and $R$ is the scalar curvature of manifold.

Can one be confident that there is a $0<f_0\in C^{\infty}(M)$ with $\int_Mf_0^2\;d\nu=1$, such that 
$\lambda(g)=\mathcal{F}(g,f_0)$?

Comment: Looks like a job for the direct method. However, the functional is not convex in $f$ due to the term $f^2\log(f)$, so there is some work to do. Another problem may be the "open" constraint $f>0$. Both problems would not be there if there would be $f\log(f)$ instead of $f^2\log(f)$. Since I do not work on manifolds, I have no idea how to formulate the respective Banach spaces (should be similar to some Sobolev or Orlicz-Sobolev spaces…).

Comment: Does your manifold have finite volume? Otherwise if you choose $f<\epsilon$ everywhere we have $\int f^2 log(f)< log(\epsilon) \int f^2= log(\epsilon)$ and $F(g,f)$ can get arbitrarily small.

Comment: Yes, the volume is finite.